# JavaScript Integration Testing

Tags: javascript, ajax, testing, phantomjs

I wish to test the full functionality of a particular JavaScript component, which makes a cross-origin ajax call. I am making use of PhantomJS to perform testing without a browser. Is there a way I can mock the origin header in this framework, so that the ajax call succeeds?

Answer (score 1):

There is a command-line switch `web-security=false` which disables cross-origin check when an ajax call is made in PhantomJS. Use it before the script argument in command line:

```
/usr/bin/phantomjs --web-security=false /path/to/script.js
```

Comment: This works if the endpoint sends "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" as a response header (I have tested that this works). What if only a few origins are whitelisted? Is that possible?